# How to copy & paste row, then delete row above to keep formula formatting on form submit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

A Google form I have created has its responses stored on a google sheet. Problem is it is adding a new row on form submit as opposed to just inserting the data into the first blank row available. This is affecting web app by removing the stored formulas from the row. How do I copy & paste data in the row above to the row below and delete the row above to keep my formula and formatting?

I have tried a rather tedious solution by using the google sheet indirect function to copy the data, but I would have to manually apply that change to the whole column and the formula cannot be auto incremented because it is absolute.

```
function Copy&paste () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Projects Created");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy&Paste");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.delete ();
}
```

I expect that on form submit the app script copies the new input from row 2 to row 3 and then deletes row 2 thus keeping my formulas intact.

Comment: if It is possible to accomplish this without app scripts that would also be helpful.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend that you don't try to edit the Response Sheets.  Let the form do it's thing and store your data and if you require a spreadsheet with cells formulas then build it on another sheet. You can get all that data sent to another form with an onSubmitForm Trigger and you can put it anywhere that you wish.

Comment: I heard that it is possible to this with an array formula, but I am unsure of how to implement it.

Comment: What is the formula you want to appear in what column?